Upper bound for the set of bad colourings
Given a complete graph of order $n$, we feel like colouring its edges red or blue.
A colouring is said to be bad if it ends up creating a red complete subgraph of order $k$ or of blue.
Let $B$ denote the set of all bad colourings.
I am into a proof of
\[
R(k, k) > 2^{k/2}.
\]
In its proof, one may almost always encounter a constructive bound for $|B|$, which is
\[
|B| \leq \binom{n}{k} 2^{
1 + \binom{n}{2} - \binom{k}{2}
}.
\]
I have a trouble with making me fully convinced that this can't be an equality. Wouldn't it be possible that for some $n$, this becomes an equality?
The order of $|B|$ is related to $R(k,k) \equiv M$; if there are $M$ vertices, and if we colour edges of complete graph of $M$ vertices, then each colouring is bad. But this number $M$ is not dependent of $n$ of our problem. The $n$ vertices only presents us a wider place where it is guaranteed that there are at least $M$ vertices.
I guess, then, there should be a specific $n_{0}$ where the bound becomes a precise value.
Any correction of my reasoning or advice would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your interest in my interest.

The upper bound for $B$ is justified by saying that for each of $\binom nk$ choices of $k$ vertices, and for each of $2$ choices of a color, there are $2^{\binom n2 - \binom k2}$ ways to color the graph so that the $k$ vertices we chose form a clique of the color we chose, and all of those colorings are bad.
To prove that it's a strict upper bound, all we need to do is say that there is at least one bad coloring that is counted twice.
This is true for all $n>k$, because in particular, if we color all $\binom n2$ edges red, then that's a bad coloring we count $\binom nk > 1$ times: once for every choice of $k$ vertices that form a red clique. Therefore, for all $n > k$, we have $|B| < \binom nk 2^{1 + \binom n2 - \binom k2}$.
Also, you would really do yourself a favor by switching to the probabilistic way of thinking from the enumerative one; it is already much cleaner here, and in more sophisticated arguments it cannot be avoided.

Thanks. And it is a hard task to reduce the bound by recognizing same colorings, I guess. Am I right to say that |B| is equal to $2^{\binom{R(k,k)}{2}}$ here?

Yes, if you mean that when $n = R(k,k)$, we have $|B| = 2^{\binom n2}$. The value $n = R(k,k)$ is by definition the point at which all colorings are bad, and there are $2^{\binom n2}$ ways to color $\binom n2$ edges.

But then, if the strict inequality holds true for each n > k, then choosing n = k + 1, we'd have  $2^{\binom{R(k,k)}{2}} < (k + 1)2^{1 + \binom{k + 1}{2} - \binom{k}{2}}$.  By this we get $ \frac{ \log 2}{2}[R(k,k) - 1]^2$ $< \log (k + 1) + (k + 1) \log 2$, by which we see that R(k, k) be bounded above by about $k^{1/2}$, a clearly wrong result (it is proved to be bounded below by $2^{k/2}$).

If you set $n = k+1$, then $n$ is no longer $R(k,k)$, so in that case, $|B|$ is not $2^{\binom{R(k,k)}{2}}$ anymore!

Oh. Is the variable n appearing in the right side of the inequality R (k, k)? But ah, I guess n is necessarily $\geq R$.
